# How to get adjacent elements of an element in 2D array programatically?

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm

Suppose you have a 2D array `arr[N][N]`. If I give an input `arr[i][j]` to you, I should get left, right, top and down elements i.e. `arr[i][j-1], arr[i][j+1], arr[i-1][j]` and `arr[i+1][j]`.
Eg: `Arr[3][3]= {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}`

- *Input: 5*
- *Output: 4, 6, 2, 8*
- *Input: 1*
- *Output: null, 2, null, 4*

How can I write a program that should consider **boundary conditions?**

Comment: `if 0 <= row_index && row_index < N && 0 <= col_index && col_index < N then print arr[row_index][col_index] else print null`

Answer (score 2):

So your program consists of two parts:

1. Finding if the input exists at some index. Find it by looping through your array, like so:

   ```
   for( int i = 0; i < N; i++ ){
       for( int j = 0; j < N; j++ ){
            if(arr[i][j] == input) //produce output
       }
   }
   ```
2. Producing output. For simplicity i will just print it out, though if your goal is a function that returns the values around the input number then you should malloc an array and copy over the values to the array. To print, check first if we are in bounds, and do not attempt to print if we are out of bounds, otherwise there will be issues.

   ```
   for( int k = i - 1 ; k < i + 2; k++ ){
       for(int l = j - 1; l < j + 2; j++ ){
         if ( k > -1 && l > -1 && k < N && j < N ){ // check if in bounds
             printf("%i ", arr[k][l]);  
         }
       }
    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

When you are accessing an index in array, just make sure that you are not accessing an invalid index, like `index < 0` or `index > size`. So in your case

```
    if(j > 0) System.out.println(a[i][j-1]);

    if(i > 0) System.out.println(a[i-1][j]);

    if(j < N-1) System.out.println(a[i][j+1]);

    if(i < N-1) System.out.println(a[i+1][j]);
```

If you want to return `null` if the index is not valid, just add in in else part for each `if`.